# How to get MS Word file binary inside of addin

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, vsto

I'm developing a VSTO addin for Microsoft Word. One of the features of this addin is that it handles the opening and saving of documents to and from a remote server. It is easy enough to make a web service call to get the file from the remote server and open it with the addin, but I cannot figure out a way to send the updated file back to the server to be saved remotely. I have tried attaching to the DocumentBeforeSave event like so

```
private void Application_DocumentBeforeSave(Document doc, ref bool SaveAsUI, ref bool Cancel)
{
    doc.Save();
    var docuBinary = File.ReadAllBytes(doc.FullName);
    // call method to upload binary
}
```

However I get an IO exception saying another process is using the file (which I'm assuming that process is word). I've tried similar strategies that involve the `SaveAs2` method with a different file name but I get the same error. I have also tried manually creating a file stream and reading from that but I get the same error.

I have gotten one way to work which is to save the document then copy it to a temp file, then read read that temp files contents and upload that. So basically this

```
private void Application_DocumentBeforeSave(Document doc, ref bool SaveAsUI, ref bool Cancel)
{
    doc.Save();
    string tempFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetRandomFileName());
    File.Copy(doc.FullName, tempFile);
    var docuBinary = File.ReadAllBytes(tempFile);
    // upload...
}
```

I'm not sure why `File.Copy` is allowed to access the file and other methods aren't (maybe File.Copy reaches out to the OS?) but, I'm just not a big fan of that method since it seems really hacky and destined to fail in some unforeseen way.

So is there a better way? Is there some method I don't know of that will send the file to a URL, is there a way of getting the raw Binary from the Document object (or some other .NET object)?

Comment: What's wrong with using File.Copy?

Comment: Technically nothing. I just don't like that I have to essentially write the file to disk. Using File.Copy is a work around and I would prefer a more direct method.

Answer (score 2):

Even though your approach using `File.Copy` works, there is another lesser known way to retrieve a file of a currently open document which is using the `IPersistFile` COM interface. This interface is implemented by the `Document` object.

The following sample saves a document to the specified location. This happens without modifying the save state of the document, i.e. you get the exact version of the document as it is open (and not as it has previously been saved to disk) and the user may later still decide to save possible modifications of the document or not.

```
public static void SaveCopyAs(this Document doc, string path)
{
    var persistFile = (System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IPersistFile)doc;
    persistFile.Save(path, false);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this is an improvement over the copy method. I still have to create a seperate file from the one that is open and then read the binary from that file.

Comment: @AndrewBonsall It gives you a copy of the document file without modifying the document - so save-state, save-timestamp etc. is not affected. And it lets you save a file copy of an unsaved document without saving first.